# OpenGL Skybox Issue

Tags: c++, opengl

There are seems on the edges of the cube that I have constructed and I cant understand why. I have set the following parameters...

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

The lines only appear sometimes, it depends on what angle the camera is sitting at. Any ideas why the lines are still there?

Comment: You are not providing enough information to make any sense of your problem.

Comment: Updated another section, hopefully that clearer

Comment: A screenshot would help as well as what the texture looks like.

Comment: Is this a cubemap texture or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was actually a problem with SOIL which is the texture loading program that I was using. After I changed the texture loading method the lines dissapeared

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could show us a screen shot. But the problem is probably the fact that you're not interpolating the textels along the edge of each face with their neighbors on the other faces.

So you should add a border to each texture by copying the edges of the neighboring textures, and change the filter mode to `GL_CLAMP`. Or you can use a cubemap texture instead.

Comment: Just using a cube map texture won't do it, I think. You also need either support for the [ARB_seamless_cube_map](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/seamless_cube_map.txt) extension or an OpenGL version where it this core (3.2, I think). But it rather sounds as if he had real hard lines in there and the seams introduced by mismatching filtering shouldn't be that significant, assuming that the textures match somehow. But well, without more information we don't know and the border idea is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to add:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

in the code you provided there is only **S** and **T** coord setup, you need the **R** as well.

Comment: The code provided doesn't use `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE`. But good to know that it's necessary for that too, I had that problem on GL3 once :)

Comment: @Kos maybe the problem is that he uses a cube map, but changes the parameters of the wrong target.